# Python scrapy cannot email html type email

Tags: python, email, scrapy

I am trying to send email scrapped item in html format.
My code is like this

```
from pscrapper import settings
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
mailer = MailSender(settings.MAIL_HOST,
                             settings.MAIL_FROM,
                             settings.MAIL_USER,
                             settings.MAIL_PASS,
                             settings.MAIL_PORT,
                             settings.MAIL_TLS,
                             settings.MAIL_SSL
                             )
html_msg = """\
<html>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
mailer.send(to=['wrufesh@gmail.com'],
            subject="New Car And Trucks From California",
            body= html_msg,
            cc=["another@example.com"],
            mimetype='html/text'
            )
```

This code sends the email but I get the mail with all HTML code.
I expect to get

```
Hello World!
```

only in email body message.
How can I achive this in scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the mime types specified [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/), you should correct your `mimetype` to

```
mimetype='text/html'
```

not `'html/text'`